# HTML <a> tag is pushing elements down the page when using position: relative

Tags: html, css

I have a form with a style input box and a `<a>` tag that acts like the form submit button. I don't want a real form button because I will be performing AJAX on this form.

Here's the markup:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="videoLink" />
    <a href="#" class="formSubmit">Go</a>
</form>
<div class="contentTop"></div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque suscipit nisi at elit elementum vitae condimentum felis aliquam. Aliquam vitae orci quis odio semper rhoncus id ut leo. Nullam laoreet semper tortor, vitae viverra est aliquam eu.</p>
</div>
<div class="contentBottom"></div>
```

And this is the style applied to the relevant markup:

```
#videoLink {
    background: url('images/inputBackground.png') no-repeat;
    width: 641px;
    height: 29px;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.formSubmit {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url('images/formSubmit.png') no-repeat;
    width: 65px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    right: -590px;
    outline: none;
}

.formSubmit:hover {
    background: url('images/formSubmitHover.png') no-repeat;
}

.formSubmit:active {
    background: url('images/formSubmitPressed.png') no-repeat;
}
```

The thing is, I get this happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXsyM.jpg

And I don't know a good solution. I need that gap where the buttons markup is to go away. When I tried to apply `position: absolute` to the `.formSubmit` element it aligns it from the top left of the window which will mess it up in different resolutions. I also tried doing the above with `position: relative` applied to the form but it just did the same.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why not style the `input` and `a` as `display: inline`, and then use `a {margin-left: -4em; }` (or something)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to document another solution: you don't need to use absolute or relative positioning to achieve what you want. "display: block" and a negative margin-top on the anchor will solve your problem. Here's a third solution based on Robert's examples:

**Top Margin:**
http://jsfiddle.net/xf2U4/

Answer (score 2):

It's doing that because that's what it's supposed to do, `position: relative` modifies it's position based on it's current location, but it's still "in" that context of the document. You will have to use `position: absolute;` or modify the `margin` to negative values until you get the desired affect.

As a side note you can use javascript to get the position of your input box relative to the document, so that it positions the same.

### Position: Absolute

http://jsfiddle.net/73MTd/

### Position: Relative

http://jsfiddle.net/YM9SB/

Comment: Is there no way I can position it relative to the form element?

Comment: You can, but you'll have to mess with CSS margin, display or other elements positioning if you want to achieve it that way.

Comment: @Will: As requested, a solution to `position: relative` has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, managed to fix it myself.

I put another DIV about my form called `aligner` and then set that to `position: relative` and then I was able to use `position: absolute` properly on the `<a>` element.

Thanks all.